# I want to choose what sites appear in my feed

Tags: feature-request, ios-app, ios-app-feed

My feed shows questions from all SE sites, most of which are irrelevant to me.

I'm interested in physics, math, and programming, topics I find served well by the SE model.  There are many SE communities I have no interest in and even get annoyed when I see the kinds of questions and answers posted (ie, opinion based answers that are passed off as truths).

It would be much better if I could manually add each site I'd like to see questions from.