# Is there a way to limit items in the iOS app's "Feed" to just mine?

Tags: feature-request, support, ios-app, ios-app-feed

The "Feed" in the (excellent) iOS Stack Exchange app includes several things that are always irrelevant to me, namely "hot" questions. Is there a way to filter them out so I only see activity related my items? Alternatively, is there a way to make the Inbox screen into the default screen?

Comment: Yes. A duplicate, not only of the linked question but also of [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220387/how-can-i-prevent-the-app-from-showing-interesting-questions-from-sites-i-don) and [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269644/i-want-to-choose-what-sites-appear-in-my-feed), which are both quite popular. A desired feature!